# Code does not look at either the return value , or the result of the program under test

Tags: php

Cannot seem to figure out how to look at the return value, or the result of the program under test.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

if ($argc < 3) {
    die("Two arguments expected: starting test value and last test value\n") ;
}

$testVal = $argv[1] ;
$lastVal = $argv[2] ;

while ($testVal <= $lastVal) {
    list ($return, $testResult) = runOneTest($testVal) ;
    checkResult($return, $testVal, $testResult) ;
    $testVal++ ;
}
// finished
exit(0) ;

/*
 * Function to test one input and check result
 *   Return an array with two entries
 *     - the return value (aka exit code) of the program being tested
 *     - the output (or result) of the progarm being tested
 */
function runOneTest($testInput) {
    $cmd = "./testProgram" ;
    exec("$cmd $testInput") ;

    // NEEDS TO BE ENHANCED
    // no output to the answer array when the exit code is > zero
    $result = 0 ; // default value
    $return = 0 ; // default value

    return(array($return, $result)) ;
}

/*
 * Function to check the results
 */
 function checkResult($retVal, $testInput, $testOutput) {
    if ($retVal == 0) {
        if ($testOutput == $testInput+1) {
            echo "Test passed for test value=$testInput", "\n" ;
        } else {
            echo "Test failed for test value=$testInput", "; result=$testOutput", "\n" ;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Test failed for test value=$testInput", "; return value=$retVal", "\n" ;
    }
 }

?>
```

Possible output

> Test failed for test value=13; return value=1
>
> Test failed for test value=14; result=13
>
> Test passed for test value=15
>
> Test passed for test value=16

Answer (score 1):

`exec` takes two optional arguments: an array reference to update with all the output of the command, and a status reference that will get the exit code of the program.

```
function runOneTest($testInput) {
    $cmd = "./testProgram" ;
    $result = array();
    exec("$cmd $testInput", $result, $return);
    $result = implode("\n", $result); // Convert result array to a string
    return array($result, $return);
}
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks, fixed it